# Two Gmail accounts exist with same email id

Tags: gmail, google-account, account-recovery

Two weeks ago I created a Gmail account with id `example@gmail.com` in my Chrome browser. I was able to login to the account from the same browser but when I tried to login using a different browser or using Chrome o another PC or in incognito mode in the same PC it always says "Wrong password. Try again".

I tried to reset my password thinking that I forgot my password. Usually when I reset password Gmail displays page in English but here I got a page in French. I thought this was just a small error and changed it to English. It asked me to type last password that I remembered, so I did. Then as usual Gmail started asking more questions to verify that the account belongs to me.

The next verification step was to enter the 'phone number to receive the verification code. It displayed this message:

> Receive SMS verification code •••• •••• XX

I didn't give any recovery 'phone number while registering or after that and this `XX` was not associated with any of my phone numbers. Here on I started having doubt that there is some serous issue with my account. I tried another question. This time it was to answer secret question and too was not set by me. So, I skipped that question also. The next question was to enter the month and year of account creation. I entered it and it displayed this:

> Enter an e-mail address that you can view immediately. You should
>   preferably use an e-mail address that you have already added to this
>   account. Google will send you a validation code at this address. Enter
>   the validation code here. If Google can verify that this account
>   belongs to you, instructions will appear to help you log in.

I entered my recovery email. I got the mail and  it was also in French. I entered the security code and after that it displayed this message.

> Thank you for validating your e-mail address. We could not confirm
>   that example@gmail.com is yours.

After all this still I'm able to login to the account that I created, using the same Chrome browser that I used for creating account. As I'm able to login I tried sending email to the same account but it failed. I'm able to send mail to other email ids. I find this very strange.

What is happening, any idea?

Comment: @pnuts I checked the past logins and i didn't show anything suspicious.

Comment: Either your accounts been hacked or your sitting behind a proxy which shows your IP as French, or you manually(accidently) changed the language on your gmail account to French.

Comment: @SleepingGod There's no proxy.

Answer (score -1):

My experience with a similar Google accounts issue causes me to think that someone else has the same email address, with the exception of an added period ".". I say this because I'm currently trying to untangle my own Gmail address, and stop getting mail from someone with my same name who just added a "." between first and last name.

I have been in contact with Google support, but unfortunately I do not yet have a definitive answer about why more than one individual is allowed to open essentially the same email address.

This may not be an answer to the question, however it may provide a different perspective on why this issue may be happening, or give some insight on similar issues Google has that may relate to yours.